# Missing labels - Cola.js/D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to adapt the below Cola.js example to use an internal json instead of a dot file

http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/unix.html

I want to use this diagram as a process diagram. Below is the fiddle that I created using an internal json -

```js
var d3cola = cola.d3adaptor().convergenceThreshold(0.1);

var width = 960, height = 700;

var outer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" });

    outer.append('rect')
       .attr({ class: 'background', width: "100%", height: "100%" })
       .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d) {
          vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
       }));

var vis = outer
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(250,250) scale(0.3)');

     outer.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
         .attr({
                id: 'end-arrow',
                viewBox: '0 -5 10 10',
                refX: 8,
                markerWidth: 6,
                markerHeight: 6,
                orient: 'auto'
            })
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5L2,0',
                'stroke-width': '0px',
                fill: '#000'});

      
    
var nodes = [
       { "nodes": "Initiate"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Send to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Finance Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Reporting Manager Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete"},
{ "nodes": "Send Notification to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Finance"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Form"},
{ "nodes": "End"}
  ];

var edges = [
{ "source": 0,     "target": 18,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 1,     "target": 20,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 2,     "target": 1,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 3,     "target": 22,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 4,     "target": 3,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 5,     "target": 25,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 4,     "target": 5,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 6,     "target": 16,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 7,     "target": 6,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 8,     "target": 19,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 7,     "target": 8,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 9,     "target": 7,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 11,     "target": 4,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 12,     "target": 11,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 13,     "target": 10,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 14,     "target": 15,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 15,     "target": 2,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 16,     "target": 14,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 17,     "target": 23,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 18,     "target": 17,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 19,     "target": 24,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 20,     "target": 23,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 21,     "target": 2,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 22,     "target": 21,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 23,     "target": 9,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 24,     "target": 12,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 25,     "target": 13,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 10,     "target": 26,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
  ];

 d3cola
       .avoidOverlaps(true)
       .convergenceThreshold(1e-3)
       .flowLayout('x', 150)
       .size([width, height])
       .nodes(nodes)
       .links(edges)
       .jaccardLinkLengths(150);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
             .data(edges)
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "link");

var margin = 10, pad = 12;
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .classed("node", true)
            .attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 })
            .call(d3cola.drag);

var label = vis.selectAll(".label")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
            .call(d3cola.drag)
            .each(function (d) {
                    var b = this.getBBox();
                    var extra = 2 * margin + 2 * pad;
                    d.width = b.width + extra;
                    d.height = b.height + extra;
             });

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("linear");

var routeEdges = function () {
           d3cola.prepareEdgeRouting();
           link.attr("d", function (d) {
                 return lineFunction(d3cola.routeEdge(d));
           });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });
            }
        d3cola.start(50, 100, 200).on("tick", function () {
              node.each(function (d) { d.innerBounds = d.bounds.inflate(-margin); })
                  .attr("x", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.x; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.y; })
                    .attr("width", function (d) {
                        return d.innerBounds.width();
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.height(); });

                link.attr("d", function (d) {
                    cola.vpsc.makeEdgeBetween(d, d.source.innerBounds, d.target.innerBounds, 5);
                    var lineData = [{ x: d.sourceIntersection.x, y: d.sourceIntersection.y }, { x: d.arrowStart.x, y: d.arrowStart.y }];
                    return lineFunction(lineData);
                });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });

                label
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + (margin + pad) / 2 });

            }).on("end", routeEdges);

        function isIE() { return ((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') || ((navigator.appName == 'Netscape') && (new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})").exec(navigator.userAgent) != null))); }
```

```css
  .background {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: white;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        cursor: move;
        fill: lightcoral;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        marker-end: url(#end-arrow);
    }

    .label {
        fill: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gugr10ve/1/

The diagram seems to render fine. However, labels inside the rectangles are missing.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong? Objective is to expand the rectangle so that the label fits in?

Thank you

Comment: got it working by changing .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
to .text(function (d) { return d.nodes; }) - http://jsfiddle.net/gugr10ve/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working by changing

```
.text(function (d) { return d.name; })
```

to

```
.text(function (d) { return d.nodes; })
```

```js
var d3cola = cola.d3adaptor().convergenceThreshold(0.1);

var width = 960, height = 700;

var outer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" });

    outer.append('rect')
       .attr({ class: 'background', width: "100%", height: "100%" })
       .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d) {
          vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
       }));

var vis = outer
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(250,250) scale(0.3)');

     outer.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
         .attr({
                id: 'end-arrow',
                viewBox: '0 -5 10 10',
                refX: 8,
                markerWidth: 6,
                markerHeight: 6,
                orient: 'auto'
            })
          .append('svg:path')
            .attr({
                d: 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5L2,0',
                'stroke-width': '0px',
                fill: '#000'});

      
    
var nodes = [
       { "nodes": "Initiate"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Send to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Finance Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of FA"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM Rejection"},
{ "nodes": "Reporting Manager Approves"},
{ "nodes": "Update Comments of RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill after WF Complete"},
{ "nodes": "Send Notification to Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Finance"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-2"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by RM"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Attachments"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions-Tracking No. Folder"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder-1"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Bill for Requestor"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on Form for Requestor Rejected by FA"},
{ "nodes": "Set Permissions on form for Reporting Manager"},
{ "nodes": "Move Bill To Tracking No Folder"},
{ "nodes": "WF Completed Permissions on Form"},
{ "nodes": "End"}
  ];

var edges = [
{ "source": 0,     "target": 18,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 1,     "target": 20,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 2,     "target": 1,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 3,     "target": 22,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 4,     "target": 3,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 5,     "target": 25,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 4,     "target": 5,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 6,     "target": 16,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 7,     "target": 6,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 8,     "target": 19,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 7,     "target": 8,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 9,     "target": 7,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 11,     "target": 4,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 12,     "target": 11,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 13,     "target": 10,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 14,     "target": 15,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 15,     "target": 2,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 16,     "target": 14,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 17,     "target": 23,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 18,     "target": 17,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 19,     "target": 24,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 20,     "target": 23,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 21,     "target": 2,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 22,     "target": 21,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 23,     "target": 9,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 24,     "target": 12,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 25,     "target": 13,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
{ "source": 10,     "target": 26,     "type": "approve"  ,     "status": "completed"},
  ];

 d3cola
       .avoidOverlaps(true)
       .convergenceThreshold(1e-3)
       .flowLayout('x', 150)
       .size([width, height])
       .nodes(nodes)
       .links(edges)
       .jaccardLinkLengths(150);

var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
             .data(edges)
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "link");

var margin = 10, pad = 12;
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .classed("node", true)
            .attr({ rx: 5, ry: 5 })
            .call(d3cola.drag);

var label = vis.selectAll(".label")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(function (d) { return d.nodes; })
            .call(d3cola.drag)
            .each(function (d) {
                    var b = this.getBBox();
                    var extra = 2 * margin + 2 * pad;
                    d.width = b.width + extra;
                    d.height = b.height + extra;
             });

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
                .y(function (d) { return d.y; })
                .interpolate("linear");

var routeEdges = function () {
           d3cola.prepareEdgeRouting();
           link.attr("d", function (d) {
                 return lineFunction(d3cola.routeEdge(d));
           });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });
            }
        d3cola.start(50, 100, 200).on("tick", function () {
              node.each(function (d) { d.innerBounds = d.bounds.inflate(-margin); })
                  .attr("x", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.x; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.y; })
                    .attr("width", function (d) {
                        return d.innerBounds.width();
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return d.innerBounds.height(); });

                link.attr("d", function (d) {
                    cola.vpsc.makeEdgeBetween(d, d.source.innerBounds, d.target.innerBounds, 5);
                    var lineData = [{ x: d.sourceIntersection.x, y: d.sourceIntersection.y }, { x: d.arrowStart.x, y: d.arrowStart.y }];
                    return lineFunction(lineData);
                });
                if (isIE()) link.each(function (d) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this) });

                label
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y + (margin + pad) / 2 });

            }).on("end", routeEdges);

        function isIE() { return ((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') || ((navigator.appName == 'Netscape') && (new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})").exec(navigator.userAgent) != null))); }
```

```css
  .background {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: white;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        cursor: move;
        fill: lightcoral;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        marker-end: url(#end-arrow);
    }

    .label {
        fill: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

jsfiddle.net/gugr10ve/2